# iOS able to play AVPlayer without waiting for AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm noticing that I can send the play message on my `AVPlayer` almost immediately without having to wait on "status" in AVPlayerItem. I'm a little confused by this. Why not play immediately?

Most examples show adding an observer on the "status" key of an AVPlayerItem. Here's some code:

```
self.asset!.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(keys, completionHandler: {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        var error:NSError?
        for key in keys {
            var status = self.asset!.statusOfValueForKey(key, error: &error)
        }

        var status = self.asset!.statusOfValueForKey("playable", error: &error)
        if status == AVKeyValueStatus.Loaded {
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.asset)
            playerItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: itemContext)
            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            playerLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            playerLayer!.frame = self.view!.bounds
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

            //self.player!.play() [This seems to work!]
        } else {
            println("Error in async load of keys")
        }

    })
})
```

The examples show that I need to implement an observer that waits until I get a status from `AVPlayerItem` and then call play on AVPlayer.

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: NSDictionary!, context: CMutableVoidPointer) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.player!.play()
        })

    super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
}
```

There are a few other SO questions on this but nobody has explained why a player can be played without having to wait for the "status" key on `AVPlayerItem`.

Answer (score 0):

you do not play immediately because data for playing may not be ready yet (poor network).

that is why player decides when to play and thats why you should observe status for AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay case.